# Save all recorded bag files acquired from a sensor using `rosbag record`

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ros, record, sensors, rosbag

I am recording data from a range scanner with "[sick_scan_xd](https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_scan_xd)" on ROS Melodic using the following command:

> rosbag record -o nav310_ws/bagFiles/session --split --duration=1 --max-splits 1 /cloud

where `nav310_ws/bagFiles` is the folder where the latest bag file is temporarily stored.

I was wondering how to save every recorded bag files, or copy each bag file to another folder, e.g., `allBags`.

I tried the following command just after the first one, but it did not do anything.

> cp -a nav310_ws/bagFiles/. nav310_ws/allBags/

My complete recording code is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f nav310_ws/bagFiles/*

while true; do  # Runs on a loop until stopped with CTRL+C
        rosbag record -o nav310_ws/bagFiles/session --split --duration=1 --max-splits 1 /cloud
done
```

Thank you for any suggestion you could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rosbag record` will always save every recorded bag file to disk, until you stop it. You should specify the output dir in the `rosbag` command. Or, if you're copying multiple files after recording you should use the `*` operator in your `cp` command, not `.`. For example: `cp nav310_ws/bagFiles/* nav310_ws/allBags/`.

Edit: The reason you're seeing only one bag file is because you're using the `--max-splits` arg and setting it to `1`. Bags will only split one time and the last bag file will be overwritten. You should up this parameter to fit your needs; or better yet, remove it.

Comment: Thanks, @BTables, for your answer. I believe that the output directory is specified, after `-o`, as `nav310_ws/bagFiles/`. An recorded bag file—which starts with `session`—is saved in this folder, then replaced with a new incoming bag file. I would like to keep all acquired bag files there, or in a separate folder, e.g., `nav310_ws/allBags/`. I have edited my question to show the complete recording `.sh` code.

Comment: @AEW sorry, I misread part of your question. I've edited my answer to include the last bit of what you're looking for.